# ASP.NET Core - How to Insert Autogenerated Id from User Model Into Merchant Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have these models in ASP.NET Core:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }
}

public class Merchant : EntityBase
{
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mandate> Mandates { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel (DTO):

```
public class RegisterDto
{
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Account Number is required")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "No white space allowed")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

EntityMapper:

```
public class EntityMapper
{
    public User FromRegisterDtoToUser(RegisterDto register)
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
            Username = register.Username,
            Password = register.Password,
        };
        return user;
    }

    public Merchant FromRegisterDtoToMerchant(RegisterDto register)
    {
        Merchant merchant = new Merchant()
        {
            MerchantName = register.MerchantName,
            AccountNumber = register.AccountNumber,
            UserId        = ?  
        };
          return merchant;
    }
}
```

AuthService:

```
    public async Task<UserDto> register(RegisterDto register)
    {
        var userExists = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetByUsername(register.Username);

        if (userExists != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("User already exists!");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                register.Password = User.ComputeSha256Hash(register.Password);

                var mapper = new EntityMapper();
                var user = mapper.FromRegisterDtoToUser(register);
                var merchant = mapper.FromRegisterDtoToMerchant(register);

                await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(user);
                await _unitOfWork.MerchantRepository.Insert(merchant);
                await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var token = GetToken(user);
                    var map = new EntityMapper();
                    return map.FromUserToUserDto(user, token);
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

UserId in Merchant is the Foreign key for Id in User. Id is autogenerated.

Since both User and Merchant Data are inserted at the same time, I want to automatically insert UserId as the Id generated from User in:

```
        Merchant merchant = new Merchant()
        {
            MerchantName = register.MerchantName,
            AccountNumber = register.AccountNumber,
            UserId        = ...?  
        };
```

How do I achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what database technology/framework you are using (I'm assuming Entity Framework) but if the `UserId` is generated upon database insert you will need to save the changes to the database after inserting user and do it again when you insert the merchant.
Basically

```
  await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(user);
  await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(); // user should have an id now.
  merchant.UserId = user.Id;
  await _unitOfWork.MerchantRepository.Insert(merchant);
  await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: I'm using EntityFramework